# GCloud deleting all documents within an Index via Gcloud or within App Engine Admin console

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gcloud, google-app-engine-python

I have a search index with several documents. I can delete using the python documentation here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/training/fts_adv/lesson3, however I was curious as to if anyone knows a way to do it via gcloud or the admin console?

I have tried via the `gcloud datastore indexes cleanup` command. and generated a index.yaml file following directons via:https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig, but it does not clear the documents away like the delete method does within python.

I didnt think the datastore one would work, for it lives within the appengine, so I am thinking i am looking in the wrong place so any help would be much appreciated! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

There is no gcloud command that will allow you to delete the documents on Datastore. There are only commands to delete the indexes or the operations which you can find over [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/datastore/).

If you are using Datastore of Firestore in Datastore mode, you can use a Dataflow job to delete a bulk of entities. There are some template jobs that you can use to do this as mentioned in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/bulk-delete).

If you want to delete a document from Firestore in Native mode, you would need to do so through the delete() method as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data), nevertheless, you would need to keep in mind that deleting a document does not delete any subcollection, you would need to retrieve the documents and subcollections in order to delete them manually [as expressed here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections).

Hope you find this useful.